# How to force date index to dataframe when concatentating

Tags: python, date, pandas, concatenation

I am trying to concat two dataframes:

DataFrame 1 'AB1'

```
           AB_BH AB_CA
Date                  
2007-01-05   305   324
2007-01-12   427   435
2007-01-19   481   460
2007-01-26   491   506
2007-02-02   459   503
2007-02-09   459   493
2007-02-16   450   486
```

DataFrame 2 'ABFluid'

```
Obj           Total Rigs
Date                                 
2007-01-03         312
2007-01-09         412
2007-01-16         446
2007-01-23         468
2007-01-30         456
2007-02-06         465
2007-02-14         456
2007-02-20         435
2007-02-27         440
```

Using the following code:

```
rigdata = pd.concat([AB1,ABFluid['Total Rigs']], axis=1
```

Which results in this:

```
           AB_BH AB_CA  Total Rigs
Date                              
2007-01-03   NaN   NaN         312
2007-01-05   305   324         NaN
2007-01-09   NaN   NaN         412
2007-01-12   427   435         NaN
2007-01-16   NaN   NaN         446
2007-01-19   481   460         NaN
2007-01-23   NaN   NaN         468
2007-01-26   491   506         NaN
```

But I am looking to force the 'Total Rigs' dataframe to have the same dates as the AB1 frame like this:

```
           AB_BH AB_CA  Total Rigs
Date                              
2007-01-03   305   324         312
2007-01-12   427   435         412
2007-01-19   481   460         446
2007-01-26   491   506         468
```

Which is just aligning them by column and re_indexing the dates.

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do `ABFluid.index = AB1.index` before the concat, to make the second DataFrame have the same index as the first.

Comment: This causes the error: ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 372 elements, new values have 393 elements    which I guess is because the two data frames are of different lengths, eventually once I put all the data together they will be the same but is there a work around for this?

Comment: @carevans88: Then that means your two DataFrames are different lengths.  What do you intend the result to be when one DataFrame has more rows than the other?

Comment: I am currently using a test run through, ill make the tests equal in length.

Comment: This worked thank you! Also, I have been working a bit with the Python for Data Analysis book but any suggestions for free courses that work with the pandas lib?